# Visual studio c++ Link1104 cannot open file MSVCURTD.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have opened  a project made with visual studio 2012 express (written in c++) with visual studio 2017 community, when I try to compile I get the following mistake:

LINK1104 cannot open file MSVCURTD.lib

(I don't have this mistake if I compile with vs 2012)
I am not a c++ expert so I don't know how to solve this problem

Thanks for your help...

Comment: upgrade the toolset from the project menu to one you have installed.

Comment: I suspect that URTD stands for Universal RunTime Debug, so you should probably rerun the installer and check that you have installed the tools for "Universal Windows Platform", and not just "Desktop development with C++".

Answer (score 6):

In the Solution Explorer, Right-click Project > Properites > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Common Language RunTime Support > choose 'Common Language RunTime Support (/clr)' > OK

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I was able to fix it as suggested by MGetz. This answer just adds more detail.

Open the project's property pages, via the Project menu (Project/Properties) or from the context menu on the project in the solution explorer.

[image]

Find **Platform Toolset** in the General section.

[image]

Open the drop down list and select <inherit from parent or project defaults> if that option is present.

[image]

This worked for me. In my case that resulted in selection of the toolset **Visual Studio 2010 (v100)**, but I think that will be dependent on what toolsets you have installed.

After selecting the toolset, Visual Studio indicates it next to the project name in the solution explorer.

[image]

If the option <inherit from parent or project defaults> is not available, then try one of the others. Since you said that your project was created with Visual Studio 2012, you should probably try selecting that version.

Answer (score 2):

I restarted installer and chose Universal Windows Platform runtime. That is correct solution because there is a real possibility that one does not have the old VC SDK version installed. If old not installed the choosing older SDK would not work. 
[image: Pic showsthe area in installer where setting can be found]

Comment: This worked for me on Visual Studio 2019 even though building **clr:pure** is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error message was caused by a /clr:pure switch of the Project.
My environment: VS2019-enterprise, Win10, today 13.1.2021
On "learn.microsoft.com" I read the article ".NET programming with C++/CLI" and complemented my VS2019 installation with the latest "C++/CLI support for v142 build tools" component.
And it worked.

sinc Ch