# c++ visual studio LNK1104 cannot open file MSVCURTD.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lnk

Hi I am working on a visual studio c++ project started on visual studio 2012, I have to adjust this project and add new functionalities, my problem is that when I try to build I get the following ERROR  "LNK1104 cannot open file MSVCURTD.lib".

Could you please tell me how to fix this error and why do I get it?!? 
Furthermore could please explain me what is MSVCURTD.lib

P.S I am using visual studio community 2017
Thanks for your help it's driving me crazy :-(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233119/cannot-open-file-sfml-system-d-lib-c#comment91415338_52233119

Comment: I have never known the project version upgrade feature to work smoothly in Visual Studio. I recommend recreating the project from scratch. Just look at the options that are set in the old project and copy over the ones you think are appropriate to the new project. You'll do a better job of this than Visual Studio does.

Comment: is `MSVCURTD.lib` listed in the library list in the linker settings? If so you should remove it. Other things to check are that the toolset setting is set to 2017 not 2012

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209046/visual-studio-c-link1104-cannot-open-file-msvcurtd-lib

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using VS 2017.

In my case changing the 'Common Language RunTime Support' from /clr:pure to /clr solved the issue.

Comment: To get there:

Right-click Project Properites > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Common Language RunTime Support